# Overbyte ICS NOFORMS mode

Tags: delphi, sockets, console-application, delphi-7, internet-component-suite

I'm trying to use Overbyte ICS TWsocket in a Delphi console application (service).
I have set `NOFORMS` in a conditionals.
But at Connect the connection doesn't go to the `wsConnected` it hangs in a `wsConnecting` state and the operation finishes with *Async socket error 10053*.

I've tried to use in a `OnMessagePump` the `ProcessMessages()`, `MessageLoop()` but it didn't change anything.

Here is a part of a code

```
inherited Create(nil);
Self.OnDataAvailable := MyOnReceive;
Self.OnChangeState := MyOnStateChange;
Self.OnMessagePump := MyMessagePump;
Addr := AIpAddress;
Port := IntToStr(AConnectionInfo.Port);
Proto := AConnectionInfo.Proto;
ComponentOptions := [wsoTcpNoDelay];
```

How to use TWsocket in a console application with NOFORMS correctly?

Comment: did you check the ICS example projects?

Comment: Great thanks! I've started to look for Examples and found them only in a http://www.overbyte.be/arch/OverbyteIcsV8beta.zip
I was using version 7 and that did not have Samples in OverbyteIcsV7Gold.zip.